# Un programa en Haskell en el cual tres de los elementos de una lista deben de ser la suma de un numero que tenemos que ingresar

Tags: haskell

Tengo que hacer un funcion en Haskell llamado `sumaDeTres` que recibe 2 entradas: un numero y una lista de numeros.

Si existen tres elementos en la lista que se pueden sumar igual al numero, la funcion devuelve `true`. Si no existen, devuelve `false`.

Por ejemplo, `sumaDeTres 10 [1,2,3,4,9,5]` regrese un `true` para comprobar que se cumple la condicion.

Habia pensado hacerlo con restara, por ejemplo restando 10 con el primer numero de la lista. Y el residuo de eso lo reste con el siguiente numero de la lista, y con el funcion `elem` encontrará si existiera algun numero con el cual cumpla.

Este metodo es utilizado en este funcion (que busca solo dos elementos en la lista):

```haskell
sumaDeDos :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int,Int) 
sumaDeDos _ [] = Nothing 
sumaDeDos _ [_] = Nothing 
sumaDeDos y (x:xs) 
   | y-x `elem` xs = Just (x,y-x) 
   | otherwise = sumaDeDos y xs
```

Pero para tres elementos, no sé como almacenar alguna variable para poder proseguir con recursividad.

Comment: sumaDeDos :: Int -> [Int] -> Maybe (Int,Int)
sumaDeDos _ [] = Nothing
sumaDeDos _ [_] = Nothing
sumaDeDos y (x:xs) | y-x `elem` xs = Just (x,y-x)
| otherwise = sumaDeDos y xs


Por ejemplo ese codigo pero para tres elementos aunque no se como almacenar alguna variable para poder proseguir con recursividad

Comment: Edita por favor tu pregunta y ahí coloca el código que has intentado

Comment: ¿Puedes explicar un poco más el ejercicio?, Si tienes un enunciado completo ayudaría aún más.

Comment: @kevindelucio debes usar el recursion (como en sumaDeDos)? o puede usar otra metoda?

Answer (score 0):

En *programación funcional* no es necesario usar *variables* para guardar estados.

Supongamos que tenemos la función `sumaDeDos` escrita para que devuelva un booleano:

```hs
sumaDeDos :: Int -> [Int] -> Boolean
sumaDeDos _ [] = False
sumaDeDos _ [_] = False
sumaDeDos y (x:xs) | (y-x) `elem` xs = True
                   | otherwise       = sumaDeDos y xs
```

La `sumaDeTres` la podemos basar en `sumaDeDos` de la siguiente forma:

```hs
sumaDeTres :: Int -> [Int] -> Boolean
sumaDeTres y ys = or [sumaDeDos (y-x) (delete x ys) | x <- ys]
```